# How to set custom colors in amCharts Column Chart?

Tags: amcharts

How do I replace default Yellow color with Red in below chart? Basically, I need to implement Red and Green combination.

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: JSFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/c3nLunv0/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lineColor and fillColors are properties of AmGraph responsible for colors.